# Using ant, check or compare all items listed in a file appear in another file or list

Tags: xml, list, ant, compare

I was wondering if you could help. I am new to ant scripting.

I want to be able to compare two lists. File1.txt will contain a list of a lot of parameters and file2.txt will only contain a section of those parameters.

File1.txt

```
dbipAddress=192.168.175.130
QAGENT_QCF=AGENT_QCF
QADJUST_INVENTORY_Q=ADJUST_INVENTORY_Q
QCREATE_ORDER_Q=CREATE_ORDER_Q
QLOAD_INVENTORY_Q=LOAD_INVENTORY_Q
```

File2.txt

```
AGENT_QCF
ADJUST_INVENTORY_Q
CREATE_ORDER_Q
```

I want to know that all the Qs in file1.txt are contained in file2.txt, after the '=', if they aren't then the ant script will stop and an Echo message will be displayed if they are then the script will move to the next .

So in the example above the script will stop as it does not contain the following Q; QLOAD_INVENTORY_Q=LOAD_INVENTORY_Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT is not a programming language, so I think you need to embed one.

The following example uses [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
<project name="demo" default="check">

    <target name="bootstrap">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.3/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="check">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
        <groovy>
            def props = new Properties()
            new File("File1.txt").withInputStream { stream -> props.load(stream) }
            def requiredValues = new File("File2.txt").text.split()

            requiredValues.each { check ->
                if (! props.find{it.value == check}) {
                    ant.fail "Cannot find ${check} in File1.txt"
                }
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```