# Verifying that two list properties in an Ant script have the same number of elements (and using them in parallel)

Tags: ant

I have a property that defines a list of files and goes through them with

```
    <foreach target="target-name" param="file"
        parallel="true" trim="true">
        <path>
            <filelist dir="${dir}" files="${files}" />
        </path>
    </foreach>
```

But I also have another property, which defines a respective "package" for each file. But how do I use the second list in parallel?

1. To verify that the ${packages} contains the same number of elements as ${files}
2. Provide the nth element of ${packages} to the target-name task that use the single file from the filelist.

or just ensure that only one file argument is provided, if I cannot verify the packages.

The properties are user configurable and will be provided from a properties file, so I don't know them in advance.

It sounds I am overreaching the capabilities of 'ant', but this is an existing script that I need to just modify to at least make sure that it cannot be run with two files and just one package. If nothing else, I would just need to detect that situation.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741906/using-ant-check-or-compare-all-items-listed-in-a-file-appear-in-another-file-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to `verify that the ${packages} contains the same number of elements as ${files}` you may use `<countfilter>` over both- `${packages}` and `${files}`, to count the number of `,` or any other `delimiter`, and compare the values to ensure the number of *elements* in `files` and `packages` are same. you may run the `<foreach>` when the the *counts* are same.

see [CountFilter](http://antcount.sourceforge.net/countfilter.html)

obtaining, in the `ith iteration of <foreach>`, the `ith elements` of `${files}` and `${packages}` respectively (assuming the order in `${packages}` conforms with the order in `${files}`) does not seem straightforward. mainly because the `<foreach>` contains **only one** `param` attribute, which therefore transfers only one *current element* of `the_input_list` as per the `delimiter` specified.
a workaround might be possible by using `<foreach>` over one list, say `${files}` and using the other list, i.e. `${packages}`, in `target-name` (by extracting one element from the list for every iteration of `<foreach>`).

how you implement this is up to you.  one example: (in `target-name`)

```
<propertyregex property="curr_pkg" input="${packages}" regexp="^(.*?)," select="\1" />
<propertyregex property="${packages}" input="${packages}" regexp="^.*?," replace="" override="true"/>
```

in every iteration of `<foreach>` and subsequent invocation of `target-name` the *first element* of `${packages}` will be available in `${curr_pkg}` and it will also be removed from `{$packages}` (or use a substitute *property* if you dont want to modify `${packages}`)

Comment: We decided to implement just the check at this point, using [ResourceCount](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/resourcecount.html) task instead of CountFilter, since it doesn't require additional task libraries. Thanks for the ideas!